# Show console output in NSScrollView and NSTextView in Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I've been learning Swift the past couple days, and I seem to have hit a rock.

I am trying to create a `ViewController` window where I have a button and an `NSViewText`. When I push the button, the app prompts the user with a sheet that has an `NSTextField`. When pressed enter, the `NSTextField` string is saved in a variable and the sheet is closed, and a terminal command is executed.

Now, my execute command method in `AppDelegate` creates a pipe with `NSPipe`:

```
let cmd = NSTask()
...
let pipe = NSPipe()
cmd.standardOutput = pipe
cmd.launch()
let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

var consoleOutput = output
return output
```

`consoleOutput` is outside the execute method, so I'm trying to display it in `ViewController`, like this:

**EDIT: Changed the previous code but still getting an error:**

```
textView.string = myDelegate.consoleOutput
```

I want the terminal output to be shown within the `NSViewText` (or `NSTextField`, or `NSScrollView`, `NSClipView`? not sure which), real time. What I cannot do is find a way to manipulate the `NSTextView`'s content, because when I run it, I get the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If assigning a  closure (e.g. code block) would work at all, you'd have to put it after an '=' in the declaration, not after the : on the LHS. You're basically trying to declare the type as a static block of code.  I'm surprised the compiler it lets you get away with that all complaining only about the IBOutlet aspect itself.

Comment: Ahh! So we can't use `IBOutlet` like we use `IBAction`! Got it. But now when I change it to `@IBOutlet var textView: NSTextView!` and use `textView.string = myDelegate.consoleOutput`, I get `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: Totally different. IBOutlet is just a tag that tells Interface Builder and the environment that it is a variable intended to receive the reference to the object defined in the storyboard or nib,  when the storyboard or nib (e.g. .xib) is loaded for your View Controller. IBAction is a tag that indicates that it is an event handler function that has been set up  to be called via the Interface Builder tools. IBOutlet is in the declaration section and non-executable, IBAction prefixes functions only.