# Print console output of a Swift application into the application itself

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm creating a GUI for a terminal command. To achieve this, I am using the following:

```
let task = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: path, arguments: arguments)
```

where `path` is the path of the executable, and `arguments` is my arguments array variable.

When this task is run in the GUI, text is output to Xcode's console, akin to what you see when you run the command in the terminal. I'd like to display this text (or the terminal output) in a Scroll View in my application. However, I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: You may be able to borrow some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308042/show-console-output-in-nsscrollview-and-nstextview-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: Here's a question and answer that may help.  It's Objective-C, but the concept should be portable.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699507/how-to-receive-output-of-nstask-in-cocoa

Comment: I'm not sure what a pipe is, so reading the answers is really funny :) Thanks for the links, I'll try to see what I can do with this information